# Extract bit from bitarray according to index list in Python?

Tags: python, list, search, indexing, bitarray

I have two [bitarray](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) objects (N.B. bitarray != BitArray) which look like

```py
a = bitarray('10010110')
b = bitarray('01001110')
```

I want a new bitarray "c" which contains the elements of a at indexes where elements of b are equal to 1. So that

```py
>> c = 0011
```

I know that doing

```py
b.search(bitarray('1'))
```

returns the list of indexes I am interested in but I cannot find a way to combine the bitarray *a* with the index list.

I know that a solution is to convert *a* to a list, use np.take to extract a list according to the index list and convert the result to bitarray. Nevertheless, this solution is too much demanding (memory and computational). My full code comprehends a kind of iteration of this operation and a test with a 1e6 array took about 10s which is way too much. I'm supposed to work with very long array (5e9) which is the reason why I chosen the bitarray library. As far as I understood, this library is the most suitable in term of memory optimization.

Here it is my "list" solution

```py
indexList=b.search(bitarray('1'))
c=bitarray((np.take(a.tolist(),indexList)).tolist())
```

Comment: `bitarray(a[i] for i in b.search(bitarray('1')))` perhaps?  Speed and memory use depend on the density of '1' bits in `b`, which you didn't specify.

Comment: please add your attempt to solve the problem

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for your suggestion! The speed improved by 5 times! Unfortunately, it is not enough;) I'm looking for another 100x speed up!
The density of 1s is very very low. Unfortunately, I have to do the same also with the 0s positions (search(bitarray('0')) so actually density doesn't matter.

Comment: @OphirCarmi I edited the question and added my attempt